# For Loop SSIS - AssignExpression

Tags: for-loop, ssis

I am newbie to SSIS so please bear with me if this question is super easy to you.

I am using a for loop container and the condition are based on variables (in the format of YYYMM), in the AssignExpression I am increment the variable by 1 which gives the next month.

How do i achieve the same functionality for year ending months?

For Example StartValue 198906:
AssignExpression (@StartValue = @StartValue + 1), so this gives me 198907, but how how i get to 198912 to 198301

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a little bit better your request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like the one below in the script task:

```
Function fctStartMonth (pStartMonth as String, pCounter as Integer) as String

    Dim intMonth as Integer
    Dim intYear as Integer

    intMonth = CInt(Right(pStartMonth,2))+  pCounter -1
    intYear = CInt(Left(pStartMonth,4))

    if intMonth > 12 then
        intYear = intYear + 1
        if intMonth = 13 then intMonth = 1
        if intMonth = 14 then intMonth = 2
        if intMonth = 15 then intMonth = 3
        if intMonth = 16 then intMonth = 4
        if intMonth = 17 then intMonth = 5
        if intMonth = 18 then intMonth = 6
        if intMonth = 19 then intMonth = 7
        if intMonth = 20 then intMonth = 8
        if intMonth = 21 then intMonth = 9
        if intMonth = 22 then intMonth = 10
        if intMonth = 23 then intMonth = 11
        if intMonth = 23 then intMonth = 12
    End If

    fctStartMonth  = CStr(intYear) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(intMonth),2)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as your assign expression:

```
@StartValue =   (DT_I4)RIGHT((DT_STR, 6, 1252)@StartValue,2)  - 12 == 0 ? @StartValue +89 :  @StartValue + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first parse a date from your initial value, such as

```
 (DT_DATE)(LEFT("201601",4)+"-"+RIGHT("201601",2)+"-"+"01")
```

Afterwards you can loop over it and use

```
DATEADD( "mm", 1, @YourDate)
```

in order to increase the value. This will handle the year change for you.